# what exactly happening when i am calling the following function called find_element_by_xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a doubt on the following  method ..

```
 driver.find_element_by_xpath
```

when i navigate via ide, i came across the following call. ->

```
def find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath):
        """
        Finds an element by xpath.

        :Args:
         - xpath - The xpath locator of the element to find.

        :Usage:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div/td[1]')
        """
        return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
```

then when i navigate to "find_element" i am getting the following

```
def find_element(self, by=By.ID, value=None):
        """
        'Private' method used by the find_element_by_* methods.

        :Usage:
            Use the corresponding find_element_by_* instead of this.

        :rtype: WebElement
        """
        if not By.is_valid(by) or not isinstance(value, str):
            raise InvalidSelectorException("Invalid locator values passed in")
        if self.w3c:
            if by == By.ID:
                by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
                value = '[id="%s"]' % value
            elif by == By.TAG_NAME:
                by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
            elif by == By.CLASS_NAME:
                by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
                value = ".%s" % value
            elif by == By.NAME:
                by = By.CSS_SELECTOR
                value = '[name="%s"]' % value
        return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT,
                             {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
```

at last i am getting the following

```
def execute(self, driver_command, params=None):
    """
    Sends a command to be executed by a command.CommandExecutor.

    :Args:
     - driver_command: The name of the command to execute as a string.
     - params: A dictionary of named parameters to send with the command.

    :Returns:
      The command's JSON response loaded into a dictionary object.
    """
    if self.session_id is not None:
        if not params:
            params = {'sessionId': self.session_id}
        elif 'sessionId' not in params:
            params['sessionId'] = self.session_id

    params = self._wrap_value(params)
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    if response:
        self.error_handler.check_response(response)
        response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
            response.get('value', None))
        return response
    # If the server doesn't send a response, assume the command was
    # a success
    return {'success': 0, 'value': None, 'sessionId': self.session_id}
```

when i use this function as below

```
apply = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='maincontent']/form/div[3]/input")
```

here i am storing the return of this function to apply and when i look for the type(apply). i am getting the following type

```
<class 'selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement'>
```

even i could able to perform the multiple same king of operation on the class methods as like below

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='cbid.vpn-g.VPN_Type.type']").find_element_by_id("cbi-vpn-g-VPN_Type-type-pptp").click()
```

can anyone please explain this to me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_element_by_xpath()` and other `find_element_by_*` methods are basically convenient shortcuts/wrappers around the main `find_element()` method which would send the [`findElement` WebDriver command](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#find-element) through the [JSON Wire protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) (RESTful JSON over HTTP).

If an element is found, `find_element()` returns a [`WebElement`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) instance which itself has all the methods mentioned above and represents a DOM element. If an element is not found by the specified locator, `NoSuchElementException` will be thrown.

Comment: i am finally ending with the function called "execute" when i navigate to "find_element_by_xpath" via ide .. how to understand these flows ...because final return will store in the instance object when call "find_element_by_xpath" right ? ..  here   return {'success': 0, 'value': None, 'sessionId': self.session_id} is the final right ?

Comment: @Bee.. sure, pay attention to the `_unwrap_value()` private method - it's actually responsible for making a web element.

Comment: @Bee.. in other words, follow everything that is happening inside the `if response:`. There is a response check (here `NoSuchElementException` would be thrown, for instance), then there is the `_unwrap_value()` call which is calling `create_web_element()` returning a `WebElement` instance.